# Argument to KnockoutJS function is returning the viewModel when not defined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Still continuing to understand KO here. I have an argument to one of the KO methods,it works when I pass it an explicit value but when I call the function with no args it does not give

```
<button data-bind="click:LaterCall">click</button>


function InvoiceViewModel() {

    //Data
    var self = this;
    self.LaterCall = function (arg) {
        console.log(arg); // why is this not undefined????
    };

}
var viewModel = new InvoiceViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/9TMv2/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout's `click` binding (and `event` binding, which `click` is a subset of) pass the current data as the first argument and the `event` as the second argument to any handlers.

So, `arg` would be equal to your `viewModel` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `arg` will reference the parent and as you can see in your example the actual viewmodel is the parent. Putting an argument there is mainly used when you have nested controllers and want to reference the parent dynamically as stated in the second example here, http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: places">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removePlace">Remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function MyViewModel() {
         var self = this;
         self.places = ko.observableArray(['London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo']);

         // The current item will be passed as the first parameter, so we know which place to remove
         self.removePlace = function(place) {
             self.places.remove(place)
         }
     }
     ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

I would also recommend you not to use `self` as a parameter name in javascript, instead go for `that`

```
var that = this;
```